# How do I `group by` rows and columns in SQLite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

## SQLite database table `table1`

```
user       command    date       location
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
user1      cmd1       2015-01-01 xxxdeyyy
user2      cmd1       2015-01-01 zzzfrxxx
user3      cmd1       2015-01-01 yyyukzzz
user1      cmd1       2015-01-01 xxxdezzz
...
```

## Expected output

Output for `where command='cmd1'`:

```
month    users_de users_fr users_es
-------- -------- -------- --------
01       1        0        5
02       2        0        0
03       0        2        1
04       5        0        15
05       1        0        4
06       11       1        2
07       9        0        3
08       1        0        5
09       0        0        5
10       0        0        0
11       1        0        0
12       1        4        5
```

It is grouped by month (from column `date`) and also grouped by a substring in location (from column `location`).

## Actual output

I can achieve this (per location):

```
month    users_de
-------- --------
01       1       
02       2       
03       0       
...      
12       1
```

using this query:

```
select strftime('%m',date) as month, count(distinct user) as users_de 
from table1 
where command='cmd1' and location like '%de%'
group by strftime('%m',date);
```

I then  repeat this query for the other locations (`where ... and location='fr'`):

```
month    users_fr
-------- --------
01       0       
02       0       
03       2       
...
12       4
```

and (`where ... and location='es'`);

```
month    users_es
-------- --------
01       5
02       0
03       1
...
12       5
```

Is there a way to have all the `users_xx` columns in one table (as output from SQLite and not through any external (downstream) processing)?

Am I thinking about this in the wrong way (grouping instead of subqueries in the top `select`)?

Comment: You can use the case for each location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select strftime('%m',date) as month, 
       count(distinct CASE WHEN location like '%de%' THEN user END) as users_de,
       count(distinct CASE WHEN location like '%fr%' THEN user END) as users__fr,
       count(distinct CASE WHEN location like '%es%' THEN user END) as users_es
from table1 
where command = 'cmd1' 
group by strftime('%m',date);
```

Two notes:

- `like` possibly isn't safe in this context.  You have the country code embedded in the string, but the characters "de", "es", or "fr" could appear elsewhere in the string.  Your question is not clear on better logic for this.
- You should include the year in the date string, but your question specifically includes only the month.

Comment: Thanks, it works! W.r.t. your two (very valid) notes:  I can be sure that the substrings do not appear elsewhere in the string; however, things may change in future and I will build in some checking (most likely in the parser feeding the database in the first place). About the year ... done! `strftime('%Y-%m',date)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the case statement to match each location and then if matches count the user.

```
    select strftime('%m',date) as month, 
           CASE WHEN location='de' THEN count(distinct user) END users-de,
           CASE WHEN location='fr' THEN count(distinct user) END users-fr,
           CASE WHEN location='es' THEN count(distinct user) END users-es,  
    from table1 
    where command='cmd1' 
    group by strftime('%m',date),location;
```

Comment: I actually have over-simplified my example. The `location` is a string that contains `de` or `es` or `fr`. Does `CASE WHEN location like '%de%'` work? What do I do about the `group by location` (because of the `like '%de%'`? Why do I need it in the first place?

Answer (score -2):

Using query like this:

```
SELECT strftime('%m',date) AS month,
       location,
       count(distinct user) AS users-de,
       count(distinct user) AS users-fr,
       count(distinct user) AS users-es
  FROM table1 
 WHERE command='cmd1' GROUP BY strftime('%m', date), location;
```

Comment: The three counts have different names, but their values are the same.